# MATLAB/Simulink serial send

Tags: matlab, serial-port, simulink

I am using [Simulink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulink) to communicate with a serial device. I am trying to use the `Serial Send` block to send a value to the device. If I try to use a 'traditional' source (such as the `Constant` block) to send data, I get the following error.

> The block 'Serial Send' cannot be assigned a continuous sample time.

How can I send a non-continuous signal?

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert signal to discreate. First put your data to Quantizer than output from Quantizer  connect "Zero-Order hold " now you send data to serial send

Answer (score 0):

Per a discussion on the MATLAB mailing list ([source](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/286149)):

> You can set a sample time on the
>   Constant block. If you double click on
>   it you will see the sample time is set
>   to -1. You can also drag in a sample
>   and hold block. You may want to turn
>   on sample time colours to make
>   debugging easier.

---

**Update**:
Also, you may want to try using the [`To Instrument`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/instrument/toinstrument.html) block instead of the [`Serial Send`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/instrument/serialsend.html) block.  I've never used either, but the main difference I see is that the `To Instrument` block is designed for sending "simulation data", which might be more compatible with the `Constant` block.  Maybe there's a reason that you can't use the `To Instrument` block, though.